# English dictionary in PHP

Tags: php, words

I'm trying to generate URLs using the convention `AdjectiveAdjectiveAnimal` and was wondering how should I do this in PHP? I'm having difficulties tracking down core PHP dictionary functions do they exist?

Comment: Whats an example of data you're starting with, what data do you want to end with, and is there anything that you've tried so far?

Comment: There are no core PHP functions which will tell you what part of speech a word is. You might have luck with an NLP library like [NlpTools](http://php-nlp-tools.com/).

Comment: Dont spam often, but my lib will do this https://github.com/lcherone/php-petname, your just want to add further animal names, fork it its free ;p

Comment: Download text files containing lists of adjectives and animals respectively. Insert the values into your database. Query database. `SELECT CONCAT(
(SELECT word FROM adjective ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
(SELECT word FROM adjective ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1),
(SELECT word FROM animal ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
) as URL;`